# C# Throw OperationCanceledException from inside CancellationToken.Register

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, cancellation

I have a long running operation that I want to cancel after, say 5 secs.  Unfortunately, polling for IsCancellationRequested is not possible (long story).

I used the code below to throw an OperationCanceledException inside the cancellation callback. I wanted to catch the exception in the main thread and handle it so that I can exit the application completely.

This doesn't seem to work properly as this results in an unhandled exception and the application doesn't terminate gracefully.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

```
    void TestTimeOut()
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cts.CancelAfter(5000);

        try
        {
            var task = Task.Run(() => LongRunningOperation(cts.Token));
            task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Operation cancelled"), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
            task.Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            //Handle
        }
    }


    void LongRunningOperation(CancellationToken token)
    {
        CancellationTokenRegistration registration = token.Register(
            () =>
            {
                throw new OperationCanceledException(token); 
            });

        using (registration)
        {
            // long running operation here
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of running something in a task if you `.Wait()` it? The use of `CancellationToken` is cooperative. Maybe you can just create a thread if you don't actually use async features (await keyword).

Comment: @DennisKuypers Other things need to be done after Task.Wait() but only if the long running task completes.  Otherwise I'd like to catch the canceled exception, do a few housekeeping and exit the application.

Comment: My point is that - if you are blocking using `Task.Wait()` why bother putting it on a different thread? There is no difference if running the long running thing on a background thread + blocking your calling thread VS just running the work on the calling thread

Comment: @DennisKuypers because I needed the task to timeout so I used CancelAfter.  I did try async/await... but the main problem here is how do I throw the OperationCanceledException properly from within the task.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the long running operation? Maybe the Cancellation can be added to it (or it offers a mechanism to actually abort the operation). Feels like the question should be about the operation and how to properly stop it instead of killing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has many No-No-es, but I guess you just using it as a demo for your problem.
The Solution is `TaskCompletionSource`, My Demo is ugly too, too many layers of Task.Run(), if you use Async, you should async all the way down. So don't use it in PRD, study `TaskCompletionSource` yourself and figure out a better solution.

```
    static void LongRunningOperation(CancellationToken token)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<int> tcs1 = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        token.Register(() => { tcs1.TrySetCanceled(token); });
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // long running operation here
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            tcs1.TrySetResult(0);
        }, token);
        tcs1.Task.Wait();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are catching an `AggregateException` but *actuall* throwing an `OperationCanceledException` which will not be caught.

Change to catch all types of exceptions such as

```
catch (Exception ex) { ... }
```

to resolve.